# Even Odd counting

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

Given an integer $Q$ and an array $A$ of size $N$, can we figure out the answer to each of the $Q$ queries?

Each query contains two integers $x$ and $y$, and we need to find whether the value $\texttt{find(x,y)}$ is odd or even:

```
find(int x,int y)
{
    if(x>y) return 1;
    ans = pow(A[x],find(x+1,y));
    return ans;
}
```

Here $\texttt{pow(a,b)} = a^b$.

Example:  Let $N=3$, the array be $[3,2,7]$, and the query be $x=1$ and $y=2$. Now do $\texttt{find(1,2)} = 9$, which is odd so answer is odd.

I know the basic approach, but what if queries can be as large as $10^5$ and same is with $N$?

Its given that $1 \leq x$, $y \leq N$, and $x \leq y$

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not a programmer, I do not understand any of this.

Comment: You should describe in words what calculation you intend for the find function to carry out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my understanding is that if we had an array `arr` like

$$[A, B, C, D, E]$$

then `find(1,2)` is $A^B$, `find(1, 3)` is $A^{B^C}$, and so on. (Similarly, `find(2,3)` would be $B^C$ and `find(2,4)` would be $B^{C^D}$. Note that we're 1-indexing). As you're always asked whether the answer is odd or even, I'll assume that none of the array elements are negative, except maybe the first one. (so that `find()` always returns an integer)

If that's the case, then for figuring out whether `find(x,y)` is odd or even, all you really need to know is whether `arr[x]` is even. If `arr[x]` is even, then so will `find(x,y)`, and similarly if `arr[x]` is odd, so is `find(x,y)`.

The only exception I can think of would be if $x+1 \leq y$ and `arr[x+1]` happened to be 0, in which case `find(x,y) = 1`, but that's an easy enough edge case to test for.

Comment: Well, without any other details, I guess a $0^0$ case is possible. My guess is that you'd return "even" in that case, but of course I don't know for sure without other details

Comment: No two consecutive numbers can be zero,also please explain how x+1<=y prooves to be a edge case

Comment: The relevant bit is that if `arr[x+1] = 0`, `find(x+1,y) = 0`, and thus `find(x,y) = 1`